# Execute function in ternary operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, jshint

I'm checking my JS files using JSHint to find mistakes.

I just got this warning :

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

```
(mandatEngagementExists)
    ? $('.mandat-type[value=1]').prop('checked', false).prop('disabled', true)
    : $('.mandat-type[value=1]').prop('disabled', false);
```

`mandatEngagementExists` is a boolean.
All my JS is in strict mode.

This piece of code is working so I wanted to know if JSHint was a bit too strict or if I should switch to a classic if/else.

Comment: See [jslinterror](https://jslinterrors.com/expected-an-assignment-or-function-call) Description. The statement think that the value returned from function call should be catched in a variable, so it says `Expected assignment`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### use boolean directly inside the `.prop("property", boolean)`

```
$(el).prop('checked', myBoolean);
```

#### Using `return`

```
function myFn() {
    /* Code here */
    return myBoolean ? $(el).doThis() : $(el).doThat();
    /* !!!!!!!!! >>> Cannot have more code here since `return` was used */
}
```

#### Using an IIFE

```
function myFn() {
     /* Code here */
    (function(){
       return myBoolean? $(el).doThis() : $(el).doThat();
    }());
     /* Code here */
}
```

#### Using `var`

```
var someVar;
function myFn() {
    /* Code here */
    someVar = myBoolean? $(el).doThis() : $(el).doThat();
    /* Code here */
}
```

#### Using `if else`

```
function myFn() {
    /* Code here */
    if(myBoolean) {
        $(el).doThis();
    } else {
        $(el).doThat();
    }
    /* Code here */
}
```

Comment: This would exit the current function

Comment: @haim770 no if you set it at function end or wrap it inside another function like an IIFE

Comment: I was just about to mention IIFE as an option. But I think the whole point here is to save some key strokes (by not using `if {} else {}`), if you're already going with an IIFE, you don't gain anything, only more code.

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer.
I'll just stay with my code, it's the shortest

Comment: @FLX you're welcome. PS,  the ***shortest possible*** is using `$(el).prop('checked', myBoolean);` as mentioned

Comment: In case of "prop" yes, but I'm also using this trick to switch between functions so it's not always possible

Comment: @FLX than you might be interested on this answer of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21520499/383904

Answer (score 2):

JSHint considers ternary operators called ignoring the return value of the called functions as bad practice.

See [Why does JSHint dislike ternaries for method calls on objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045918/why-does-jshint-dislike-ternaries-for-method-calls-on-objects)

you can ignore the warning, set a fake variable

```
var temp=(mandatEngagementExists)
    ? $('.mandat-type[value=1]').prop('checked', false).prop('disabled', true)
    : $('.mandat-type[value=1]').prop('disabled', false);
```

or use this

```
/*jshint expr:true */
```

Comment: Good answer. Personally I'd just switch to an `if/else` – makes the intention a whole lot clearer. Code is read far more often than it is written, after all.

Comment: Thanks. This jshint expression will be useful.